# undefined index file (Tried a lot of solutions from this forum but not working ...)

Tags: php, html, undefined-index

I'm sorry to ask question that has been seen a lot of time, but it seems to not work for me, so I have to ask you guys ...
Thanks in advance !

here is my html form :

```
<form action="action/actionindex.php" method="post">
<label style="text-align:center;"><b>Changer d'image</b></label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="indeximage" style="margin-left:500px;"/>
    <div class="bg" style="background-image:url('../image/papierpeint.jpg');width:95%;margin:0 auto;height:auto;">
        <div class="welcometxt">
            <ul>

                <label><b>Titre de l'article (Saut de ligne : <img src="../image/sautligne.png"/>| Gras : <img src="../image/gras.png"/>| Italique : <img src="../image/italique.png"/>| Souligné : <img src="../image/souligne.png"/>)</b></label>
                <textarea name="indexh2" rows="1" cols="80">
                    <?php getDesc(1) ?>
                </textarea></br>
    <label><b>Contenu l'article (Saut de ligne : <img src="../image/sautligne.png"/>| Gras : <img src="../image/gras.png"/>| Italique : <img src="../image/italique.png"/>| Souligné : <img src="../image/souligne.png"/>)</b></label>
            <textarea name="indexp" rows="15" cols="110">
                <?php getDesc(2)?>
            </textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modifier"></br>
```

and here is actionindex.php :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];  
    echo 'nom : '.$name;
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
    echo 'dossier temp : '.$temp_name;
    if(isset($name)){
        if(!empty($name)){      
            $location = '../../image/';      
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location)){
                echo 'File uploaded successfully';
            }
        }       
    }  else {
        echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
    }
}
```

Hope you guys help me, thanks !!

Comment: If `$_FILES["file"]` gives `undefined index file` then there were no uploaded files. That could be because you're missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form.

Comment: Wow it actually worked !! Thanks for that quick answer !! How do I put this thread in solved?

Comment: Cool. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$_FILES["file"]` gives `undefined index file` then there were no uploaded files.

You're missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form.

Answer (score 0):

when your form includes any `<input type="file">` elements use multipart/form-data:

```
<form action="action/actionindex.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Read more about multipart/form-data [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Answer (score -3):

Try to change your form code as below:

```
<form action="action/actionindex.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I hope, it helps.